# How to use MediaStore.createDeleteRequest?

Tags: java, android, delete-file, mediastore, android-music-player

I was just wondering how to use MediaStore.createDeleteRequest() to create a delete request for a music/mp3 file. Because of the new ScopedStorage I am not able to use File.delete() and I cannot find some examples on how to use MediaStore.createDeleteRequest(). It would really be helpful if someone gives me a example on how to use it delete music files. Thanks

Comment: You did not google for createdeleterequest.

Comment: Not a good post but has a good example: https://proandroiddev.com/scoped-storage-on-android-11-2c5da70fb077

Comment: I did google but I didn't find good resources

Comment: The link i provided is from the google search i suggested. No reason why you should not have found it. You can repeat the search to check.

Comment: Hey @blackapps, I checked the link you provided. But the code is written in kotlin. And I use java so I cannot understand the code as I am a beginner android developer :< . Would really like some help :>

Comment: Then look further for other examples.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try https://medium.com/@vishrut.goyani9/scoped-storage-in-android-writing-deleting-media-files-ee6235d30117

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    val pendingIntent = MediaStore.createDeleteRequest(context.contentResolver, mutableListOf(fileUri))
    deleteResultLauncher.launch(IntentSenderRequest.Builder(pendingIntent.intentSender).build())
} 

private val deleteResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()) { result ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Log.d("deleteResultLauncher", "Android 11 or higher : deleted")
    }
}
```